# migration fails when changing column data type to timestamp with change() in laravel 6

Tags: laravel

I wanted to change a column type from `integer` to `timestamp` with new migration, but when I try to migrate it doesnt work and it shows an error

> Doctrine\DBAL\Exception  : Unknown column type "timestamp" requested.
> Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with
> \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list of all the
> known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap(). If this
> error occurs during database introspection then you might have
> forgotten to register all database types for a Doctrine Type. Use
> AbstractPlatform#registerDoctrineTypeMapping() or have your custom
> types implement Type#getMappedDatabaseTypes(). If the type name is
> empty you might have a problem with the cache or forgot some mapping
> information.
> I could migrate other migrations that have timestamp datatype but without change() function, so the problem is when using change() with timestamp data type.

I tried to do whats laravel 8 documentation suggests [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#prerequisites) but still getting the same error, any advice how to solve this issue.
I am using laravel 6.

migration up function:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('testassignment', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->timestamp('duration')->nullable()->change();
        });
    }
```

Comment: It appears that while what the L8 documentation suggestion works. It only works for L8 and above so if you really must use timestamps then either upgrade or do a raw query that alters your table

Comment: @apokryfos thanks, yes with laravel 8 it should work but I'm using La6, what do u mean to alter my table, like delete the whole table and creating it again, or something else?

Comment: @zahidhasanemon thanks, it seems to be the same question

Comment: Instead of using `Schema::table`... you could also do `DB::statement('ALTER TABLE testassignment MODIFY duration TIMESTAMP)` and to rollback you do the reverse (note I haven't tested this but I don't see why it wouldn't work).